# Changing the value of a variable inside an inner class

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Android Studio to create an app and simulating the back-end database using Firebase. Currently, I am trying to enable the app to take in and display data that I enter in through Firebase.  While I am using the Firebase data snapshot method to capture data, I am unable to save and use the data due to the fact that the snapshot occurs within an inner class.

For example, in Firebase, I have assigned the value of "Fri" to "2 steps". If you look at the code below, the first print statement (inside the inner class) prints "Friday Steps: 2 steps", but the second print statement (outside the inner class) prints "Friday Steps: null". This is a problem because I need to be able to use the correct value of fridaySteps (as well as the String variables of the other weekdays), in later assign statements that assign values to mDataset.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String[] mDataset = new String[7];
    String fridaySteps;
    String thursdaySteps;
    String wednesdaySteps;
    String tuesdaySteps;
    String mondaySteps;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mDataset[0]= "";
        mDataset[1]= "";

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

        Firebase ref = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL);

        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                fridaySteps = snapshot.child("Fri").getValue(String.class);
                thursdaySteps = snapshot.child("Thu").getValue(String.class);
                wednesdaySteps = snapshot.child("Wed").getValue(String.class);
                tuesdaySteps = snapshot.child("Tue").getValue(String.class);
                mondaySteps = snapshot.child("Mon").getValue(String.class);

                System.out.println("Friday Steps: "+fridaySteps);

            }
            @Override public void onCancelled(FirebaseError error) { }
        });

        System.out.println("Friday Steps: "+fridaySteps);

        mDataset[2] = ("Fri      "+fridaySteps);
        mDataset[3] = ("Thu      "+thursdaySteps);
        mDataset[4] = ("Wed      "+wednesdaySteps);
        mDataset[5] = ("Tue      "+tuesdaySteps);
        mDataset[6] = ("Mon      "+mondaySteps);

    }
}
```

Does anyone have advice for how I could fix this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Can you assign the values of `mDataset` inside of `onDataChange`? You don't have them initially because retrieving the data from Firebase is asynchronous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since retrieving your Firebase data is asynchronous, you wont be able to access it right away.

Assign your values to `mDataset` inside of `onDataChange` for use later. Like this:

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

        fridaySteps = snapshot.child("Fri").getValue(String.class);
        thursdaySteps = snapshot.child("Thu").getValue(String.class);
        wednesdaySteps = snapshot.child("Wed").getValue(String.class);
        tuesdaySteps = snapshot.child("Tue").getValue(String.class);
        mondaySteps = snapshot.child("Mon").getValue(String.class);

        mDataset[2] = ("Fri      "+fridaySteps);
        mDataset[3] = ("Thu      "+thursdaySteps);
        mDataset[4] = ("Wed      "+wednesdaySteps);
        mDataset[5] = ("Tue      "+tuesdaySteps);
        mDataset[6] = ("Mon      "+mondaySteps);

        printData();

    }
    @Override public void onCancelled(FirebaseError error) { }
});

...

private void printData() {
    System.out.println("Friday Steps: "+fridaySteps);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is occurring because addValueEventListener is asynchronous, When addValueEventListener is executed, the next step is printh the second System.out.println("Friday Steps: "+fridaySteps), for this reason it is returning null, it doesnt wait that addValueEventListener finished. 
On the other hand, the first System.out.println("Friday Steps: "+fridaySteps) will wait that addValueEventListener  finished, then it will print the message.